# An approach to deserialize string a content

Tags: c#

I have a custom formatted string read from a text file that has multiple occurrences of an instance of a template.

To clarify

I have a string template

```
--------------------
Id : {0}
Value : {1}
--------------------
```

I have read a text file whose content is as follows

```
--------------------
Id : 21
Value : Some Value 1
--------------------
--------------------
Id : 200
Value : Some Value 2
--------------------
--------------------
Id : 1
Value : Some Value 3
--------------------
--------------------
Id : 54
Value : Some Value 4
--------------------
```

I have `class A` which has 2 public properties Id and Value

```
class A
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to deserialize the whole text read from the text file to  `List<A>`.

An approach without the "for" "foreach" or "while" loops would be better.

Comment: Sooner or later a loop is required

Comment: Or a custom serializer according to your need.

Comment: @Steve True. You cannot repeat actions without a loop.

Comment: lol. You could pretend your loop was something else e.g. hide it in a function call. But computers are very good at loops, why pretend?

Comment: There is no way to do this without a loop at some point, unless you want to hardcode the whole file. Even then you're just unwrapping the loop for the compiler, so it won't be more efficient than a loop anyway.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh can you explain please.

Comment: I would assume the most efficient way is a stream reader, taking lines as you need them and parsing them. It will need a while loop. Can you explain why you want to avoid looping?

Comment: @kidshaw to save performance.

Comment: @Subhasis That makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Unless you have a fixed file format with a defined number or records so you substring everything - you're not going to get anything more performant. If you think otherwise I'd look carefully at what you're doing within the loop to see if that can be improved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can modify your A class to have constructors like the following:

```
class A
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    
    public A() { }

    public A(string s)
    {
        string[] vals = s.Split((new string[] { "\r\n" }), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        this.Id = vals[0].Replace("Id : ", string.Empty).Trim();
        this.Value = vals[1].Replace("Value : ", string.Empty).Trim();
    }

    // only overridden here for printing
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id : {0}\r\nValue : {1}\r\n", this.Id, this.Value);
    }
}
```

You could implement something of the following:

```
public static List<A> GetValues(string file)
{
    List<string> vals = new List<string>(Regex.Split(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file), "--------------------"));
    vals.RemoveAll(delegate(string s) { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim()); });
    List<A> ret = new List<A>();
    vals.ForEach(delegate(string s) { ret.Add(new A(s)); });
    return ret;
}

public static void Main()
{
    foreach (A a in GetValues(@"C:\somefile.txt")) {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

Your original question asked to avoid loops; this doesn't have an explicit loop construct (`for`, `foreach`, `do/while`), but the underlying code does loop (e.g. the `Regex.Split`, `vals.RemoveAll` and `vals.ForEach` are all loops), so as the comments have pointed out, you can't really avoid loops in this scenario.

It should be noted that after some benchmarks, this method is surprisingly fast if the file to be read is in the exact format you have specified. As a comparison, I created a file and copy/pasted your example template (the 4 results you have posted) for a total of 1032 results and a file size of ~75k, the XML file resulted in about 65k (due to the less text of the `---`), and I wrote the following benchmark test to run:

```
public class A
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public A() { }

    public A(string s)
    {
        string[] vals = s.Split((new string[] { "\r\n" }), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        this.Id = vals[0].Replace("Id : ", string.Empty).Trim();
        this.Value = vals[1].Replace("Value : ", string.Empty).Trim();
    }

    public A(string id, string val)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Value = val;
    }

    // only overridden here for printing
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Id : {0}\r\nValue : {1}\r\n", this.Id, this.Value);
    }
}

public static List<A> GetValuesRegEx(string file)
{
    List<string> vals = new List<string>(Regex.Split(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file), "--------------------"));
    vals.RemoveAll(delegate(string s) { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim()); });
    List<A> ret = new List<A>();
    vals.ForEach(delegate(string s) { ret.Add(new A(s)); });
    return ret;
}

public static List<A> GetValuesXml(string file)
{
    List<A> ret = new List<A>();
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer srl = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(ret.GetType());
    System.IO.FileStream f = new System.IO.FileStream(file,
                                                      System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
                                                      System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                                                      System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite);
    ret = ((List<A>)srl.Deserialize(f));
    f.Close();
    return ret;
}

public static List<A> GetValues(string file)
{
    List<A> ret = new List<A>();
    List<string> vals = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file));
    for (int i = 0; i < vals.Count; ++i) {
        if (vals[i].StartsWith("---") && ((i + 3) < vals.Count) && (vals[i + 3].StartsWith("---"))) {
            ret.Add(new A(vals[i + 1].Replace("Id : ", string.Empty), vals[i + 2].Replace("Value : ", string.Empty)));
            i += 3;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static List<A> GetValuesStream(string file)
{
    List<A> ret = new List<A>();
    string line = "";
    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
    int state = 0;
    A a = null;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        line = line.Trim();
        if (!line.StartsWith("-") || line.Length > 0) {
            switch (state) {
                case 0:
                    if (line.StartsWith("Id")) {
                        string[] inputArray = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                        a = new A();
                        ret.Add(a);
                        a.Id = inputArray[1].Trim();
                        state = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (line.StartsWith("Value")) {
                        string[] inputArray = line.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                        a.Value = inputArray[1].Trim();
                        state = 0;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

public static void Main()
{
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
        double avg = 0d;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            sw.Restart();
            List<A> txt = GetValuesRegEx(@"C:\somefile.txt");
            sw.Stop();
            avg += sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("avg: {0} s", (avg / 100)));
        // best out of 5: 0.002380452 s
        avg = 0d;
        sw.Stop();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            sw.Restart();
            List<A> txt = GetValuesXml(@"C:\somefile.xml");
            sw.Stop();
            avg += sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("avg: {0} s", (avg / 100)));
        // best out of 5: 0.002042312 s
        avg = 0d;
        sw.Stop();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            sw.Restart();
            List<A> xml = GetValues(@"C:\somefile.xml");
            sw.Stop();
            avg += sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("avg: {0} s", (avg / 100)));
        // best out of 5: 0.001148025 s
        avg = 0d;
        sw.Stop();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            sw.Restart();
            List<A> txt = GetValuesStream(@"C:\somefile.txt");
            sw.Stop();
            avg += sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("avg: {0} s", (avg / 100)));
        // best out of 5: 0.002459861 s
        avg = 0d;
        sw.Stop();
    }
    sw.Stop();
}
```

For clarity, here are the results when run on an Intel i7 @ 2.2 GHz with a 5400 RPM HDD (with about 0.1% fragmentation):

> `GetValuesRegEx` run time best average out of 5 runs: 0.002380452 s
>
> `GetValuesXml` run time best average out of 5 runs: 0.002042312 s
>
> `GetValues` (`ReadAllLines`/loop) run time best average out of 5 runs: 0.001148025 s
>
> `GetValuesStream` (`StreamReader`/loop) run time best average out of 5 runs: 0.002459861 s

Your results may vary and this does not take into account ***any*** error handling, so you'll need to take that into account when using the code.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Using string split method is more efficient than using regex split in this case.  ReadAllText is a waste of memory.  Read one line at a time is more efficient.

Comment: @jdweng, completely agree, which is why I made a note about the posted code not being efficient; the OP was asking how to do it without looping (hence the answer posted).

Comment: @txtechhelp Thanks. This is a better & new approach.

Comment: @jdweng I too agree with you, but that was a requirement.

Comment: SubHasis : See my answer.  StreamReader will read strings like the posting requested.

Comment: Excellent form adding the benchmarks. Loops still have it :)

Answer (score 2):

I have been parsing text files like this for 40 years.  He is the best method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        enum State
        {
            FIND_ID,
            FIND_VALUE
        }
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<A> a_s = new List<A>();
            string inputLine = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            State state = State.FIND_ID;
            A a = null;
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (!inputLine.StartsWith("-") && inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    switch (state)
                    {
                        case State.FIND_ID :
                            if (inputLine.StartsWith("Id"))
                            {
                                string[] inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                                a = new A();
                                a_s.Add(a);
                                a.Id = inputArray[1].Trim();
                                state = State.FIND_VALUE;
                            }
                            break;
                        case State.FIND_VALUE:
                            if (inputLine.StartsWith("Value"))
                            {
                                string[] inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                                a.Value = inputArray[1].Trim();
                                state = State.FIND_ID;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class A
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: My code should run quicker with less memory.  See my comments against accepted answer.  Accepted answers are often accepted by the same person who wrote the posting.  My answer has 20 upvotes.

Comment: Just an FYI: I'm not the OP. @kidshaw, check my edited answer for benchmarks .. surprisingly the `Regex` is really fast and to be honest I didn't expect the results I obtained, but those are the results I got ..?? .. I'd be interested to see if others have similar results

Comment: How was the memory usage?  How big was you input file?  The bigger the file the more memory will be used and the efficiency will decrease exponentially.  My method the speed will be linear and the memory will be constant.